# Is there an exception that would rollback an Django atomic transaction without being propagated?

Tags: django

I created an exception

```
class MyOwnRollBack(Exception):
    pass
```

only to be able to rollback a transaction without it being raised beyond the transaction:

```
try:
    with transaction.atomic():
         # do stuff
         raise MyOwnRollBack
except MyOwnRollBack:
    pass
```

Is there an exception that `transaction.atomic()` won't let propagate, similar to this code I wrote?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an exception that transaction.atomic() won't let propagate, similar to this code I wrote?

Technically, yes, but for all practical purposes, no.

IntegrityErrors will escape

```
try:
    with transaction.atomic():
        generate_relationships()
except IntegrityError:
    handle_exception()
```

but once you get to `handle_exception()` the transaction has *already* been rolled back. Even if it wasn't rolled back, you're not allowed to run database statements before the rollback is finished (a `TransactionManagmentError` will be raised).

You might find a solution handling transactions manually, check the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/transactions/#transactions

Comment: ps: the `__exit__` function of `.atomic()` is here https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/transaction.py#L204